# Java abstract classes/interfaces and specifying type parameters

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, overriding

Right now I'm implementing a `Tree<T>` (`<T>` refers to the data value of the root node) abstract class and currently have something like this:

```
public abstract class Tree<T> {
    public void setChild(int index, ??? childTree);
    public void deleteChild(int index, ??? childTree);
    public T getData();
    public void setData(T value);
}
```

As you could see, I'm having trouble figuring out the correct type for the child trees.  Ideally, I'd do something like this

```
public abstract class Tree<T> {
    public void setChild(int index, ImplementingClass childTree);
    public void deleteChild(int index, ImplementingClass childTree);
    ...
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do this (probably going to reread the docs).  The current solution I have in mind is something like this

```
public abstract class Tree<T, C extends Tree> {
    public void setChild(int index, C childTree);
    public void deleteChild(int index, C childTree);
    ...
}
```

But a more correct solution would be to specify that a child tree has to be the same class as the current tree.  Is there a way to specify this in Java?

Comment: what is `T`????

Comment: There's no self type in Java . What you have in mind looks mostly correct. It should be `Tree<T, C extends Tree<T, C>>`.

Comment: Does it really have to be the same implementation? Isn't having `Tree<T>` as a parameter good enough?

Comment: Right, thanks @shmosel.  The inconsistency (self type is the correct behavior not a generic subtype) really bothers me though.  @sidgate, `T ` is, generally, the key/value of the tree/node.  Though there are also problems with just `T`, consider a 2-3 tree.  What is `T` then!?

Comment: @JornVernee as I see it, yes.  There's really no reason you would want to add a Binary Tree (or even worse a BST or a Red-Black tree) to a N-ary tree.  This is just the first case I thought of, there's plenty more examples where mixing Tree types is problematic.

Comment: <T extends Tree<T>>

Answer (score -1):

```
Tree<T>
```

will contains object of type T

```
Tree<String> tree;
```

T could be another generic type description

```
Tree<Tree<String>>
```

Then you add or delete T objects from it

```
Public void setChild(int index, T child);
public void deleteChild(int index, T child);
```

if you want to specify T to a more restrictive type

```
<T extends class>
<T implements interface>
<T super class>
```

in the first example if you haven't method implementations, change abstract class to interface.

remember that a class can inherit from only once other but can implements multiple interface

Comment: Ah, I'd like to keep the generic type `T` to refer to the data value of the root node.  Having the data value itself be a child tree would be confusing since we already have a list/collection of children trees.

Comment: ok then you're right with Tree<T, C extends Tree> child tree has the same root type? maybe Tree<T, C extends Tree<T, C>>